# How does strcat() fucntion actually works and its alternate

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, strcat

Let's take an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str1[7] = "hello ";
    printf("Initial size of str1 is: %d\n", strlen(str1));
    char str2[] = "buddy";
    printf("%s\n", strcat(str1, str2));
    printf("Final size: %d\n", strlen(str1));
}
```

The output of the above program will be

```
Initial size of str1 is: 6
hello buddy
Final size: 11

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.835 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

See? how the size of `str1` changed from 7 to 11 (including null variable), regarding that what I think would have happened is :

- Some function I do not know may have reallocated contiguous memory for `str1` starting from same address as before i.e `str1` with size `strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1` *+1 for null value*, and then redefined it to get **hello buddy**.

If I am wrong please tell, if not then, what function is it and how does it work?

One more question: how can I write a code to do the above task without the use of `strcat` function.

I tried doing it using `realloc()` but didn't quite succeed may be that's because `realloc()` can only reallocate dynamically allocated memory, is it so?

Comment: You just overflowed buffer where `str1` points to. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: And there is nothing with dynamic memory allocation. All strings are located on stack.

Comment: "is it so?" The [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3p.html) provides the answer: "If ptr does not match a pointer returned earlier by calloc(), malloc(), or realloc() or if the space has previously been deallocated by a call to free() or realloc(), the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Buffer overflow**

OP's code fails as `strcat(str1,str2)` attempts to write past the end of `str1[]` - result: *undefined behavior* (UB).  [@dimich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204284/how-does-strcat-fucntion-actually-works-and-its-alternate/73204634#comment129286753_73204284)

Instead use a larger destination buffer.

```
// char str1[7]="hello ";
char str1[7 + 5]="hello ";
char str2[]="buddy";
printf("%s\n",strcat(str1,str2));
```

**Use correct print specifier**

`strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

```
// printf("Initial size of str1 is: %d\n",strlen(str1));
printf("Initial size of str1 is: %zu\n",strlen(str1));
```

Tip: enable all warnings.

**Alternative**

One of many alternatives: copy `str2` to the end of `str1`.

```
// printf("%s\n",strcat(str1,str2));
strcpy(str1 + strlen(str1), strt2);
printf("%s\n",str1);
```

**`realloc()`**

> `realloc()` can only reallocate dynamically allocated memory, is it so?

`realloc()` should not be used on pointers to non-allocated, non-`NULL` pointers.
In addition to *re-allocating* dynamically allocated memory, `realloc()` can start with no prior allocation.

```
char *p = realloc(NULL, size);
// just like
char *p = malloc(size);
```

**Moral of the story**

- Be mindful of memory usage with *string* functions.
- Enable all warnings.

Comment: can you please explain what does `strcpy(str1 + strlen(str1), str2);` actually does 
when i used `strcpy(str1 + strlen(str2), str2);` it returned _hellobuddy_ else it works completely fine.

Comment: and yea i got your point about buffer overflow but why does it gives required output every time even if i change string in _str1_ even when memory is statically allocated??

Comment: @Raon `strcpy(str1 + strlen(str1), str2);` determines the location of the _null character_ with `str1 + strlen(str1)` as that is the _length_ of the _string_ from its beginning.  `strcpy(str1 + strlen(str1), str2)` then copies `str2` to that location - the end of `str1`.

Comment: @Raon `strcpy(str1 + strlen(str2), str2);` should form _hellobuddy_ as the length of `str2` is one less than `str1`, so the copying destination starts one character earlier, overwriting the `' '`.

Comment: @Raon Writing beyond the end of `char str1[7]` is UB.  It might return what you want, it might freeze the program, it might ...  It is _not_ defined.  Your _every time_ is not that many times, not with many compilers, not with many platforms, etc.  To form the correct output every time for you, me and others on other computers, other compilers, we need to use a destination buffer of sufficient size like  `char str1[7 + 5];`.

Comment: @Raon If you need a language that catches your mistakes, C is not the language for you.  C trusts the programmer is doing the right thing and so does not need to add lots of run-time checks that slow things down.  C is [compact, powerful, goes everywhere](http://s3.crashworks.org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/if-programming-languages-were-vehicles/)

Comment: so basically `str1+strlen(str1)` is defining from which point of index str2 should be copied?? where `str1` is the target point and `strlen(str1)` gives index from which it should start copying?
and one more thing how does this not cause buffer overflow? str1 is still defined to be of 7 characters!

Comment: is somehow the size of the _array storing str1 increases_?

Comment: @Raon: the *size* of the array `str1` does not change, only the *length* of the C string it contains does. The array`str1` must be defined with a large enough size to accommodate the final string plus a null terminator: `6 + 5 + 1` bytes.

Comment: @Raon "str1+strlen(str1) is defining from which point of index str2 should be copied" --> Yes.  Calculating an address within an array, or one past it not UB.  Attempting to store past the arrays' end is UB.  Once an _array_ is defined, its size cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can only reallocate the memory you have dynamically allocated (ie using `malloc` family functions).

> ee? how the size of str1 changed from 7 to 11 (including null
> variable), regarding that what I think would have happened is : A
> function idk which one, but it may have reallocated contiguous memory
> for str1 starting from same address as before i.e str1 with size
> strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1 +1 for null value, and then redefined it
> to get hello buddy. If i am wrong please tell, if not then , what
> function is it and how does it work?

2. You are wrong. It is an example of an Undefined Behaviour. You have written some data outside array memory. Undefined Behavior means that your program behaviour from now is unpredictable. `strcat` **does not** reallocate any memory.

> At last, how can i write a code to do the above task without the use
> of strcat function.

For example:

```
char *mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src, const int isDynamicMemory)
{
    size_t dlen = strlen(dest);
    size_t slen = strlen(src);

    if(isDynamicMemory)
    {
        dest = realloc(dest, slen + dlen + 1);
        if(!dest) return NULL;
    }
    memcpy(dest + dlen, src, slen + 1);
    return dest;
}
```

If `dest` was dynamically allocated you can reallocate it to the correct size by passing `1` as `isDynamicMemory` parameter

3. Try to do not program in the `main` function. Use functions for such task like writing `strcat` like function.

Comment: buddy can you please explain your program starting from first if statement, i m quite the 
beginner so :(

Comment: take paper and pen. Execute the function yourself. You will understand it

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior because in the call of `strcat`

```
printf("%s\n", strcat(str1, str2));
```

the memory beyond the character array `str1` declared like

```
char str1[7] = "hello ";
```

is being overwritten.

There is no space in the array to accommodate the string `"buddy"` after the stored string `"hello "`.

The sizes of the array `str1` and str2 themselves was not changed. The function `strlen` does not return the size of a character array. It returns the length of a string: a sequence of characters terminated by the zero-terminating character `'\0'`. To get the size of a character array you should use the operator `sizeof`.

Pay attention to that the return type of the function `strlen` is `size_t`. To output a value of this type you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d`.

```
printf("Initial size of str1 is: %zu\n", strlen(str1));
                                 ^^^
```

To make the program correct you have to enlarge the character array `str1`. Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str1[12] = "hello ";
    
    printf( "The size of str1 is: %zu\n", sizeof( str1 ) );
    printf( "The length of the stored string in str1 is: %zu\n", strlen( str1 ) );

    char str2[] = "buddy";

    printf("%s\n", strcat(str1, str2));

    printf( "The size of str1 is: %zu\n", sizeof( str1 ) );
    printf( "The length of the stored string in str1 is: %zu\n", strlen( str1 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
The size of str1 is: 12
The length of the stored string in str1 is: 6
hello buddy
The size of str1 is: 12
The length of the stored string in str1 is: 11
```

As you can see from the output the size of the array `str1` stays unchanged. What was changed is the length of the stored string in the array `str1`.

Pay attention to that the function `strcat` does not allocate or reallocate memory for arrays passed to the function as arguments. So if the destination array does not have enough memory to accommodate the appended string then the behavior is undefined because in this case the memory after the destination array will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in the comment, overflow of `str1` occures. `strcat()` doesn't know where and how strings are allocated. It searches end of destination string and appends source string overwriting null terminator.
If you want dynamic allocation, it could be:

```c
    char str1[]="hello ";
    printf("Initial size of str1 is: %zu\n", strlen(str1));
    char str2[]="buddy";
    char *str3 = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
    if (!str3)
        return 1;
    strcpy(str3, str1);
    strcat(str3,str2);
    printf("%s\n",str3);
    printf("Final size: %zu\n", strlen(str3));
    free(str3);
```

This may be optimized little bit. `strlen()` calculates length of string at runtime and you have strings known at compile time. So we can use it:

```c
    char str1[]="hello ";
    printf("Initial size of str1 is: %zu\n", strlen(str1));
    char str2[]="buddy";
    char *str3 = malloc(sizeof(str1) + sizeof(str2) - 1);
    if (!str3)
        return 1;
    strcpy(str3, str1);
    strcpy(str3 + sizeof(str1) - 1, str2);
    printf("%s\n",str3);
    printf("Final size: %zu\n", strlen(str3));
    free(str3);
```

Also pay attention to `strlen()` return type: it is `size_t`. We should either cast it to `int` for printing with `%d` format or print with `%zu`.

EDIT: fixed length calculation, fixed printf formatting modifier.

Comment: Or even `memcpy(str3, str1, sizeof(str1)-1); memcpy(str3 + sizeof(str1)-1, str2, sizeof(str2));` instead of both `strcpy()`.

Comment: I think casting the `size_t` to `int` is pretty unhealty because `size_t`'s max value is way greater in every implementation I am aware of, and casting also adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Brogolem35 Of course `%z` is preffered.  I just don't remember what standard defines it. But in this case lengthes are definetly fit into `int`. Wrong output will be on very long strings but behavior will be still defined.

Comment: I couldn't find a source but from what I remember it was defined in C99.

Comment: @dimich "I just don't remember what standard defines it."  `z` prefix came up in C99.  To portable print a `size_t` in C89, code used `printf("%lu\n",(unsigned long) strlen(str1));`, something that worked very well back then and even today.

Comment: `char *str3 = malloc(sizeof(str1) + sizeof(str2));` is **very confusing**. It actually allocates one byte too many and good compilers will compute the allocation size at compile time for `char *str3 = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);` without any risk of confusion and more importantly without undefined behavior in case `str1` or `str2` are changed from arrays to pointers in a separate edit.  To prove my point, the urge for premature optimisation bit you immediately: `strcpy(str3 + sizeof(str1), str2);` is incorrect! it should have been `strcpy(str3 + sizeof(str1) - 1, str2);`.

Comment: I am downvoting your answer until you fix it.

Comment: @chqrlie You are right about length calculations, it's my mistake. Thank you for pointing. But i disagree about confusing by changing array to pointer when valriable is declared in the same funciton. A developer must know what he/she is working with. I've seen many times when relying on optimizer made O(2) instead of O(1) because of redundant length calculations. Better approach is to call `strlen()` once at the begginning and use stored value, of course. Please leave your downvote as is, it also matters.

Comment: Since you are adamant about optimisation, you might also replace `strcpy(str3, str1); strcpy(str3 + sizeof(str1) - 1, str2);` with `memcpy(str3, str1, sizeof(str1) - 1); memcpy(str3 + sizeof(str1) - 1, str2, sizeof(str2));`... why use `strcpy` when the sizes are known, especially at compile time.
`

Comment: @chqrlie I noted this in first comment. Profit of `memcpy()` is linear, just copying machine words instead of chars and different stop condition, which is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

As other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73204634/16835308), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73204636/16835308)) mentioned, your code has a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), a kind of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

> One more question: how can I write a code to do the above task without the use of strcat function.

Either:

1. Use `snprintf()`
2. Use `strlcpy()`
3. Implement your own version of `strcat()` (with some potential improvements)

---

**Option 1**

```
char str1[] = "hello ";
char str2[] = "buddy";
    
size_t total_size = sizeof(str1) + sizeof(str2) - 1; // sizeof counts \0 at the end
char res[total_size];

snprintf(res, total_size, "%s%s", str1, str2);

printf("sizeof(str1) = %zu\n", sizeof(str1));
printf("sizeof(str2) = %zu\n", sizeof(str2));
printf("total_size   = %zu\n", total_size);
printf("res = %s\n", res);
```

```
sizeof(str1) = 7
sizeof(str2) = 6
total_size   = 12
res = hello buddy
```

`snprintf()` lets you to control how many characters at most you want to print. This is comes handy in preventing a buffer overflow. For example, if you use `sprintf(res, "%s%sxxx", str1, str2)` in the above code, you'll get a BO. This is not the case with `snprintf(res, total_size, "%s%sxxx", str1, str2)`.

---

**Option 2**

`strlcpy()` lets you to control how many characters at most you want to copy, and guarantees null-termination (unlike `strncpy()`). Possible implementations: [1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/master/libcutils/strlcpy.c), [2](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/osfmk/arm/strlcpy.c.auto.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933725/my-version-of-strlcpy).

---

**Option 3** (credit: [Back to Basics](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/))

```
char *concatenate(char *dest, char *src)
{
    while (*dest) dest++;
    while ((*dest++ = *src++));
    return --dest;
}
```

Or:

```
char *concatenate_n(char *dest, char *src, int n)
{
    while (*dest) dest++;
    for (int i = 0; i < n && (*dest++ = *src++); ++i) {}
    return --dest;
}
```

Example:

```
char str1[12] = "hello ";
char str2[] = "buddy";

concatenate(str1, str2);
// concatenate_n(str1, str2, sizeof(str1) - 1 - strlen(str1)); // Remaining space in str1

printf("str1 = %s\n", str1);
printf("p    = %s\n", p);
```

Comment: "strcpy() is very prone to BO: if str2 is larger than what str1 can hold, your code may behave in an undefined manner." --> so does `strncpy(str1 + strlen(str1), str2, strlen(str2));`.  Using `strncpy()`, as posted here, has no benefit over `strcpy(str1 + strlen(str1), str2);`, just more complexity.

Comment: `concatenate_n()` is not _safer_ than `concatenate()` for similar reasons.  A _safe_ concatenation function would use the size of the destination to limit copying.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have edited the code, Now, both `strncpy()` and `concatenate_n()` accept as a third argument the remaining space available in the destination buffer: `sizeof(str1) - 1 - strlen(str1)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `sizeof(str1)` is the total capacity, `-1` because of the counted `\0`, and `strlen(str1)` to exclude the used space. What remains is the free space available. Thanks for your comment btw.

Comment: I removed the DV, but there are still some problems: `concatenate_n` does not null terminate the destination array if `n < strlen(src) + 1`. You should model this function after `strlcat`, with a prototype `char *concatenate_n(char *dest, size_t n, const char *src)` where `n` is the length of the array pointed to by `dest`, much simpler to pass than the available size at the end of `dest`.

Comment: @chqrlie OK. I'll fix that. Again, thanks a lot.